# elements get dropped when I use jquerys replaceWith() in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my site I have an `li` list which I want to be able to sort. I've made a function that does and then calls `renderOutput()` with the sorted list. Now I want to update the current list I have with the sorted list.

so I use this:

```
function renderOutput(list) {
    list_original = getList(); //list_original is how it looks from beginning
    list_original.forEach( (element, index) => {
        // list_original and list is always the same length
        // for each element in original list, replace with the corresponding in the sorted list
        $(element.element).replaceWith(list[index].element);
    }); 
}
```

But it seems like the jquery function replaceWith corrupts the lenght of the list. Before after this function the length of the list is lower than before. (So if I run this i will eventually get a list with 1 item).

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: why replace individual list elements rather than the entire list?

Comment: So you mean I should create an new `ul` list and put the elements in that one, and then replace my `ul` list on the page with the new, updated one?

Comment: yes, that was my initial thought. then you don't need to worry about arrays becoming corrupted or whatever else, you just swap out the whole `ul`

Comment: Yea thats smart. Will try it, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the list and append it back to the `<ul>`:

```js
$('ul').append($('li').sort(function(a, b) {
  return $(a).text() - $(b).text();
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```